# How to accomplish the following using SQL commands?

Tags: sql, t-sql, teradata

Here is the sample table that I have:

[image]

For argument sake, please note that there won't be more than 3 items sold by any restaurant (even in the future).

Comment: What have you tried so far? And from this screen shot it's not clear (to me) what exactly you want to do?

Comment: What have you tried? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `N/A` does that mean NULL, or is it a value?

Comment: `tsql` or `teradata`? `CASE` over `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

**If no more that 3 items sold, the fixed query might be:**

```
SELECT 
  tr.name restaurant
  , tr.is_open open
  , max(case when rn=1 then item_sold end) item_sold_1
  , max(case when rn=2 then item_sold end) item_sold_2
  , max(case when rn=3 then item_sold end) item_sold_3
FROM restaurants tr LEFT JOIN 
( select restaurant_id, item_sold
    ,row_number() over (partition by restaurant_id order by 1) rn from items_sold
) ti
ON (tr.restaurant_id=ti.restaurant_id)
GROUP by tr.name, tr.is_open, 3;
```

**Table structures:**

```
create table restaurants
(
restaurant_id integer primary key not null,
name varchar(255),
is_open varchar(3)
);

create table items_sold
(
item_entry_id integer primary key not null, 
item_sold varchar(255),
restaurant_id integer references restaurants
);
```

If more that 3 items are needed, you will have to generate the SQL dynamically, based on the unique value count in the items_sold object.